# Django Wagtail [Errno 111] Connection refused form submission

Tags: django, wagtail

I have a site that I made using Wagtail (Django) and set up a contact form with a landing page. When using this contact form on localhost, I can successfully add information on the contact form and submit it, which takes me to the landing page.

However, I have hosted this on heroku, and now have a problem with submitting the contact form. When I have submitted the contact form, it gives me an error that the connection was refused [Errno 111]:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wagtail/core/views.py", line 24, in serve
    return page.serve(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wagtail/contrib/forms/models.py", line 300, in serve
    form_submission = self.process_form_submission(form)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wagtail/contrib/forms/models.py", line 341, in process_form_submission
    self.send_mail(form)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wagtail/contrib/forms/models.py", line 346, in send_mail
    send_mail(self.subject, self.render_email(form), addresses, self.from_address,)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wagtail/admin/mail.py", line 62, in send_mail
    return mail.send()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 284, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 102, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 62, in open
    self.connection = self.connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 253, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 339, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 308, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 808, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 796, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)

Exception Type: ConnectionRefusedError at /contact/
Exception Value: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I'm not sure if this error is occurring because of incorrectly set up email settings, or whether it is looking for localhost on the redirect to the landing page.

This is my environment:

```
Django Version: 3.1.5
Python Version: 3.8.5
Installed Applications:
['home',
 'search',
 'flex',
 'streams',
 'site_settings',
 'subscribers',
 'blogsite',
 'projects',
 'contact',
 'wagtail.contrib.forms',
 'wagtail.contrib.redirects',
 'wagtail.contrib.settings',
 'wagtail.contrib.routable_page',
 'wagtail.contrib.sitemaps',
 'wagtail.contrib.modeladmin',
 'wagtail.embeds',
 'wagtail.sites',
 'wagtail.users',
 'wagtail.snippets',
 'wagtail.documents',
 'wagtail.images',
 'wagtail.search',
 'wagtail.admin',
 'wagtail.core',
 'modelcluster',
 'taggit',
 'djrichtextfield',
 'wagtailfontawesome',
 'wagtailcodeblock',
 'wagtailuiplus',
 'wagalytics',
 'wagtail_blocks',
 'wagtailstreamforms',
 'wagtail_color_panel',
 'wagtailcaptcha',
 'widget_tweaks',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps']
Installed Middleware:
['django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'wagtail.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware']
```

An example of one of the traceback details showing localhost. I'm not sure if Heroku works through its own localhost, or whether this is the source of the rror:

[image]

Interestingly though, the data from the form is captured and shows up in my form data page in the admin:
[image]

Any ideas what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's failing to send the email notification because you don't have an SMTP backend. You'll need to configure one - see

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/email/#smtp-backend

Heroku makes it easy to connect with a range of SMTP providers:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/smtp

We use Mailgun, which has a generous free tier:

https://elements.heroku.com/addons/mailgun

If you don't care about sending emails, you can just push them to the console backend:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/email/#console-backend

Comment: Thanks, seems I had this setup as console backend, and when using the email to and email from it was throwing this error. I have fixed that and migrated it to heroku and installed mailgun, but I am still having the issue when specifying emails to send to and from. It is currently in sandbox mode (had a problem upgrading so contacted their support). Is mailgun t supposed to work 'out of the box' (added myself to list of approved emails too)?